# how can select the value of dropdown when check the check box group using jquery

Tags: jquery

i need to try select the dropdown, when i was checked the check box value that corresponding value was selected in the  dropdown

For example when i checked the Test 2 ,the dropdown also chage the selected value as Test 2

and i need check box group code..

```
<html>
<head><title>Check Box</title>
<script>
$("#chk").click(function(){
$("#test option:selected")=$("#chk :checked").val()
});
</script>
</head>
<form>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="chk">Test 1
<input type="checkbox" value="2" id="chk">Test 2
<input type="checkbox" value="3" id="chk">Test 3
<select id="test">
<option value="1">Test 1</option>
<option value="2">Test 2</option>
<option value="3">Test 3</option>
</select>
</form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#chk").click(function(){
    if( $(this).is(':checked') )  // or   if( $(this).attr('checked')== true) )
    $("#test").attr('value', $(this).attr('value'));

});
```

Answer (score 2):

**HTML**

```
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="chk1">Test 1
  <input type="checkbox" value="2" id="chk2">Test 2
  <input type="checkbox" value="3" id="chk3">Test 3
  <select id="test">
    <option value="1">Test 1</option>
    <option value="2">Test 2</option>
    <option value="3">Test 3</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(':checkbox').change(function() {
    // uncheck previously checked checkbox
    // becasue select can show one value
    // at a time

    $(':checkbox:checked') // select all checked checkbox
           .not(this)  // escape the current checkbox
           .prop('checked', false); // making uncheck

    // change the select box value

    $('#test').val(this.value);

});
```

***Problem in your code:***

- `type="checbox"` should be `type="checkbox"`
- Don't use same `id` for all `checkbox`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L35Jt/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/EZEQu/

Few things were wrong. the demo is basic demo you can play around and enhance.

- HTML `type=checkbox`
- id Needs to be unique all the time
- `<script>` tag worth putting `type` attribute in it as well.

Hope this helps,

**code**

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){

    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
        $("#test").val($(this).val());
});​
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head><title>Check Box</title>

</head>
<form>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="chk">Test 1
<input type="checkbox" value="2" id="chk1">Test 2
<input type="checkbox" value="3" id="chk2">Test 3
<select id="test">
<option value="1">Test 1</option>
<option value="2">Test 2</option>
<option value="3">Test 3</option>
</select>
</form>
</html>​
```